# Git to show last changes of a file

Tags: git, diff

I googled about this and a lot of articles showing how to see changes in either last few days or last commits.

What I really want is to see the last change to a file regardless when and which commit.

Lets say, I have FileA and FileB

commit 1: changed FileA and FileB

commit 2~99: changed FileB

What I want to see is what was the last change to FileA without knowing which commit affected FileA.

This is particularly useful (at least for me) when I git pull a shared project, I see a big list of files changed by a number of commits, I am interested what changes have been made to some of the files, but it's kind of hard to do.

Comment: So to clarify, if you have commit 1 which changes file A, commit 2 which changes it again, and commit 3 which reverts commit 2, you only want to see the changes in commit 3?

Comment: well not very sure, cos when I get a git pull, I see a list of files changed, but it's kind of hard to find which commit affected the file I want to diff.

Comment: For that, my choice would be to use `git log --stat HEAD@{1}..HEAD`. (But it doesn't answer the question you actually asked.) Or, do see the diff of that one file, `git diff HEAD@{1} path/to/file` (which combines all the commits you just pulled).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply try

```
git log -1 -p -- path/to/your/file
```

Like git help says:

```
  -<n>
       Limits the number of commits to show. Note that this is a commit
       limiting option.

  [--] <path>...
      Show only commits that are enough to explain how the files that
      match the specified paths came to be. See "History Simplification"
      below for details and other simplification modes.
```

Comment: This will show the commit affected the file I assume? Is there a simple command to give me the diff straight away?

Comment: @JamesLin You can add the `-p` option to get the diff out

Answer (score 0):

1. git diff HEAD^^ myfile
2. git log -p